# CRM 2011 - outlook connector always asking for authentication

Tags: authentication, outlook, login, microsoft-dynamics-crm

In my organization everyone uses the Outlook 2010 connector to access the CRM.
After the UR13 update, but not right away, some clients began experiencing a situation where the Outlook connector asks for login every time they double-click an entity in a list, thus when opening a new window. It's the typical ADFS login form, displayed into the new window in place of the entity they chose to open. Sometimes also opening a list (e.g. Accounts, Activities, ...) causes the login form to be displayed embedded into outlook's center frame.
Either way, the credentials entered won't stick and in many cases a reboot is necessary. Sometimes I have to un-configure and re-configure the org with the Configuration Wizard to make it go away. But after a while it strikes back.

Unfortunately our setup is not a very standard one - the CRM-running machine (2008R2 all patched) is on its own domain in the same network with our primary one... which is incompatibly samba3-based. All users are mirrored in the two domains. Though I feel this is not the culprit.

Anyway, we've tried everything, from adding even junk to trusted sites, messing with IE settings, storing passwords in vault, fiddling with IIS authentication providers - no way. We're at stand still.

Any idea?

Thanks

**ADDENDUM:** I forgot to mention that sometimes when it's not working we get a dialog saying "Waiting for a page to load from the CRM server", and a slow progress bar that smells timeout'ty (but the CRM is responsive via web). When it closes, the contents of Outlook's CRM ribbon is replaced by a string "A page failed to load from the server", or something along the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Check that IE setting "Empty Temporary Internet Files when browser is closed" is clear. If checked, and using IE and Outlook, then Outlook will prompt for log in because closing windows in IE collapses the session.

HTH.